# c# writing/reading CSV

Tags: c#, csv

I'm working on a program in C #. With this program it is intended that I write values ​​from a textbox to a CSV file. This works so far though. Only the values ​​pasted back together like this:

```
hellobye|
hello (TextBox1)
bye (TextBox2)
```

How do I get that they always come on a new line? I've already tried Environment.NewLine, just not got working.

This is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                String input = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text;
                string[] lines = {input  + "|" };
                System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(@"c:\output.csv", lines);
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox2.Clear();
            }

          }
    }
}
```

Comment: CSV means *Comma* Separated Values.  it appears you are trying to use a *Pipe* as a delimiter.

Comment: And your output is exactly what you told it to be.  If you want it to be something else, then you should tell it to be something else.

Comment: And Dan-o, how do I what you say? I don't understand how.. The input should be on a new line in my CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I'm correct, your current output is "hellobye|"

but you want it to be 
hello
bye

So if you are creating a csv then you would want to delim your elements with commas, and then insert newlines for the rows.  So a quick console app would look something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string string1 = "hello";
        string string2 = "bye";

        string[] lines =
            {
                string1 + 
                Environment.NewLine + 
                string2
            };

        System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(@"c:\output.csv", lines);
    }
```

where the string1 & string2 would simply function as the output from the text boxes

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use an StreamWriter.WriteLine method example of use:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to. 
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Hello");
                sw.WriteLine("And");
                sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
            }
        }

        // Open the file to read from. 
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            string s = "";
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
String input = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text;
```

You are lumping the contents of the two text boxes together into one word, and after that the system can no longer tell where one words ends and the next begins.